# Decomposition of induced representation from index 2 subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, $N$ a subgroup of index $2$, and $V$ an irreducible representation of $N$.

*Question*: How $\mathrm{Ind}_{N}^{G}(V)$ decomposes? Can we write explicitly the irreducible components?

---

*Context*: this question is motivated by [a dual version of Ore's theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/195366/34538). Let $[H,G]$ be a boolean interval of finite groups and $N \in [H,G]$ with $|G:N| = 2$ and $[H,N]$ linearly primitive (as interval). Then the answer of Derek Holt helped me to prove that $[H,G]$ is also linearly primitive.

Comment: It might be helpful for you to google the phrase "Clifford theory" keeping in mind that index two subgroups are automatically normal.

Comment: It depends whether $V$ extends to an irreducible representation of $G$. If so, then it extends to two such representations, and the induced representation  is the sum of these. Otherwise the induced representation is irreducible.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Are there explicit conditions for your first or second case  (using for example the conjugate representations $V^g$)? Can the first case be written explicitly?

Comment: @Nate: yes thanks. I expect that for the index $2$ case, we can have a result more explicit and easy.

Comment: @DerekHolt: What's the point to put on hold a question with an accepted answer. Anyway, I've edited the post with the expected context.

Comment: Sorry, I have voted to reopen now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corollary (6.19) of Isaacs, Character Theory of Finite Groups says that, if $N$ is normal in $G$ with $|G:N|=p$ prime and $\chi \in {\rm Irr}(G)$, then $\chi_N$ is either irreducible or a sum of $p$ distinct conjugate irreducible characters.

Let $\psi \in {\rm Irr}(N)$.

If $\psi = \chi_N$ for some $\chi \in {\rm Irr}(G)$, then $\psi^G$ is the sum of $p$ distinct irreducible characters of $G$, all having restriction $\psi$. Conversely, if $\psi^G$ is the sum of $p$ irreducible characters of $G$, then by frobenius reciprocity they must all reduce to $\psi$. In this case $\psi$ is fixed by conjugation by all elements of $G$.

Otherwise $\psi^G=\chi$ is irreducible. Then the second case of the result in Isaacs must apply to $\chi$, so $\chi$ has $p$ distinct conjugates under $G$.

This is all assuming that we are talking about complex representations. In the more general case it could be possible that $\psi^G$ was irreducible and reduced to to the sum of two copuies of $\psi$, but I have not thought about that.

Comment: Very nice!! Can we expect something even more explicit for $p=2$?   (I'm talking about complex representation).

Comment: I don't know what you mean here by more explicit!

Comment: As you wrote, if $\mathrm{Ind}_{N}^{G}(V)$ is not irreducible, then it decomposes into two irreducible extensions from $N$ to $G$ of $V$. Can we build explicitly these extensions?

Comment: $|G:L| = 2$, so $G = L  \sqcup L \tau$. If, for example, $ \forall n \in N$, $\pi_{V}(\tau n \tau^{-1}) = \pi_{V}(n) $  then $V$ extends to $G$ as $V_{\pm}$ with $\pi_{V_{\pm}}(\tau) = \pm id$. Is there such a construction in general (i.e. without assuming $V^{\tau} = V$)?

Comment: You cannot necessarily define $\pi_V(\tau) = \pm I$, because $\tau^2 $ could be a nontrivial element of $H$. That would not work in the cyclic group of roder $4$ for example. The general problem of explicitly extending extendible representations is not easy, although there are computational approaches.

Comment: [$L=N$ in my previous comment]

Comment: Assume that $\mathrm{Ind}_{N}^{G}(V)$ is not irreducible and let $π_1$ be an irreducible extension of $π_V$ from $N$ to $G$. Then the extension $π_1$ is completely characterized by $π_1(τ)$. Now we can build the other irreducible extension $π_2$, as characterized by $π_2(τ)=−π_1(τ)$.